# The reason behind {block:Title} in Tumblr theme?

Tags: tumblr

Out of curiosity, what's the reason behind using `{block:Title}` instead of just `{Title}`:

```
{block:Title}
  {Title}
{/block:Title}
```

I do it because Tumblr tells me to, but was wondering if there was a good reason for it. If it's to run conditionally (i.e. to show title when there is one), wouldn't `{Title}` alone suffice since it's a variable, as it displays nothing when there is no title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's the blocking point?

> If it's to run conditionally (i.e. to show title when there is one), wouldn't {Title} alone suffice since it's a variable (i.e. it displays nothing when there is no title)?

Whilst strictly true, as no string is rendered if no `title` exists, markup will still be rendered. For example, lets pretend the title is empty.

**Markup**

```
<h2>{Title}</h2>
```

**Output**

```
<h2></h2>
```

This would be undesired. However, combine `title` with `{block:Title}`.

**Markup**

```
{block:Title}    
<h2>{Title}</h2> 
{/block:Title}
```

**Output**

```
<!--nothing to see-->
```

*tl;dr* - Always use the blocks, to stop empty elements being created.